# how to remove association in sequelize without extra query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have many to many association between `exercise` and `muscle` models.
I remove single association

```
models.Exercise.find({where: {id: exerciseId}})
                .then(function(exercise){
                    exercise.removeMuscle(muscleId);
                    res.sendStatus(200);
                });
```

ORM runs 3 queries and 2 of them are similar

```
Executing (default): SELECT `Muscule`.`id`, `Muscule`.`title`, `Muscule`.`description`, `Muscule`.`video`, `Muscule`.`createdAt`,
    `Muscule`.`updatedAt`, `muscle_exercise`.`createdAt` AS `muscle_exercise.createdAt`, `muscle_exercise`.`updatedAt` AS `muscle_
    exercise.updatedAt`, `muscle_exercise`.`MusculeId` AS `muscle_exercise.MusculeId`, `muscle_exercise`.`ExerciseId` AS `muscle_exercise.ExerciseId` FROM `Muscules` AS `Muscule` INNER JOIN `muscle_exercise` AS `muscle_exercise` ON `Muscule`.`id` = `muscle_exercise`.`MusculeId` AND `muscle_exercise`.`ExerciseId` = 11;



 Executing (default): SELECT `Muscule`.`id`, `Muscule`.`title`, `Muscule`.`description`, `Muscule`.`video`, `Muscule`.`createdAt`,
    `Muscule`.`updatedAt`, `muscle_exercise`.`createdAt` AS `muscle_exercise.createdAt`, `muscle_exercise`.`updatedAt` AS `muscle_
    exercise.updatedAt`, `muscle_exercise`.`MusculeId` AS `muscle_exercise.MusculeId`, `muscle_exercise`.`ExerciseId` AS `muscle_exercise.ExerciseId` FROM `Muscules` AS `Muscule` INNER JOIN `muscle_exercise` AS `muscle_exercise` ON `Muscule`.`id` = `muscle_exercise`.`MusculeId` AND `muscle_exercise`.`ExerciseId` = 11;


    Executing (default): DELETE FROM `muscle_exercise` WHERE `ExerciseId` = 11 AND `MusculeId` IN (52)
```

Is there any way to avoid duplicate query? And it would be perfect if I can escape first and second query and run only third one that actually do something useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like in [documentation using `set` function](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/docs/associations.md#associating-objects) passing array of associated objects without the one you try to remove. But this basically leaves you with three queries anyways.

In order to make it in just one DELETE query you need to add a tie model in your code. In your case it will look something like this:

```js
models.Exercise = sequelize.define("exercise", {
   /* attributes */
});

models.Muscle = sequelize.define("muscle", {
   /* attributes */
});

models.exercise_muscle_tie = sequelize.define("exercise_muscle_tie", {
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});

models.Exercise.belongsToMany(models.Muscle, { as: 'muscles', foreignKey: 'exerciseId', through: models.exercise_muscle_tie });
models.Muscle.belongsToMany(models.Exercise, { as: 'exercises', foreignKey: 'muscleId', through: models.exercise_muscle_tie });
```

After you defined it and associated it with `belongsToMany` to the models your *remove script* will be:

```
models.exercise_muscle_tie.destroy({ where: { exerciseId: 1856, muscleId: 57344 } })
```

Generated SQL:

```
Executing (default): 
DELETE FROM `exercise_muscle_tie` WHERE `exerciseId` = 1856 AND `muscleId` = 57344
```